# Why is this insertion sort missing the first element?

Tags: python, insertion-sort

Need help with this insertion sort implementation:

```
def insertion_sort(list):
    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        element = list[i]
        for j in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
            if list[j] > element:
                list[j+1] = list[j]
            else:
                break
        list[j+1] = element
    return list
```

When i run it with `list = [200, 2, 56, 234, 5, 21]`
it returns: `[200, 2, 5, 21, 56, 234]`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way:

```
def insertion_sort(list1):    
    
    for i in range(1, len(list1)):  

        value = list1[i]   
          
        j = i - 1  
        while j >= 0 and value < list1[j]:  
            list1[j + 1] = list1[j]  
            j -= 1  
        list1[j + 1] = value  
    return list1  
       
list1 = [10, 5, 13, 8, 2]  
print("The unsorted list is:", list1)  

print("The sorted list1 is:", insertion_sort(list1))
```

Comment: You might want to describe why this is different: in brief, `for j in range(i-1, -1, -1)` never sets `j` to `-1`, the range stops iterating first. In contrast, `while j >= 0` does allow `j` to read `-1` as the loop ends. That makes the assignment at the end always correct, rather than off by one if you iterated to the end.